# How to access virtual remember_token attribute in the integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I'm working on michal hart's Ruby on rails tutorial  at chapter 8 
[Click here for details](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#code-improved_remember_me_test), I get stuck at exercise 8.6, The author introduced a way to access the virtual remember_token attribute in the integration test and he left some work for us,

```
assert_equal assigns(:user).FILL_IN, FILL_IN
```

Im supposed to replace the correct code with "FILL_IN" placeholder. I just couldn't think of the correct one. I tried with

```
assert_equal assigns(:user).cookies, remember_token
```

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
     @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in @user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      redirect_to @user
```

But it didn't work, 
 Erros:

```
 "test_login_with_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 0.590876]
 test_login_with_remembering#UsersLoginTest (0.59s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `cookies' for #<User:0x007f964f1a91d0>
```

I know it's something very simple, I actually did some research , it seems no one has asked the same question, because the tutorial is quite new.
   Please understand that I'm just a beginner,I would be greatly appreciated , if you can help  me to solve  this problem.

Comment: You are using cookies as user attribute or user method. You could translate 'assigns(:user).cookies' as @user.cookies what is wrong (cookies do not depend of user & are stored in computer, not in rails application).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have got the answer by purchasing Michael's book. And the answer is included in the solution manual.  I think it's worth to share since i have asked this question

```
assert_equal assigns(:user).remember_token, cookies['remember_token']
```

It's worth nothing that, Reading about ruby language will be greatly helpful to understand this code,My problem was i didn't do much reading about Ruby before I dive in rails studies, But it's not a big problem, I have just moved on to Ruby beginning in order to get a deeper understanding about Ruby language! 
                  Good luck

Comment: I still have an error, not sure why:      NoMethodError: undefined method `remember_token' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Hey  i would suggest you to check out michael's github repo. it's all in there.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error when I tried like @Snailwalker

`assert_equal assigns(:user).remember_token, cookies['remember_token']`

But it works like this

`assert_equal assigns[:user].remember_token, cookies['remember_token']`